# Implementing `Monad ((->) e)`

Tags: haskell, monads

[Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) presents this exercise:

> Implement a Monad instance for ((->) e).

Here's the `MyMonad` class.

```
class (MyMonad m) where
    ret     :: a   -> m a
    flatMap :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Then, I begin to attempt to implement the Monad instance for `((->) e)`.

```
instance (MyMonad (-> e)) where
    ret x       = ...
    flatMap m f = ...
```

But, I don't have intuition for what `((->) e)` means.

Please help me understand it, as well as give me a hint towards solving for `ret`.

Comment: First off, you need to understand parametric types: so if I write `data Foo x = ...` I have a family of types, and we could call that an "abstract type" `Foo`. (The official description is that `Foo` is a type of kind `* -> *` so that putting in any type of kind `*` gives a type of kind `*`.) If you understand that, then `(->) a` is a type of kind `* -> *`, just like `Foo` is when we specify `data Foo x = ...`. It is the abstract-type of functions which take an `a` as an argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's something of a syntax trick going on here. It might be easier to think of `(->) e` as `(e ->)` or, even more clearly, if we write

```
type Arr a b = a -> b
```

then `(->) e` is about the same as `Arr e`.

So what is the type of `ret`? It ends up as

```
ret :: a -> (e -> a)
```

which should be more solvable now.

Comment: Is this the GHC vesrion of `(-> e)`? `Prelude> let f = return (+ 10) |||
Prelude> (return 10) >>= (\x -> fmap ($ x) f) === 20`

Comment: There's a lot going on in that code snippet. I'm not sure what you're asking, I suppose.

Comment: I'm asking if my 2 lines of code demonstrate the expected behavior of the `(->) e` Monad - per my above question that you kindly answered.

Comment: No, your code is actually generic in the choice of monad. If you type it into GHCi you'll see `:t f` give you `f :: (Num a, Monad m) => m (a -> a)` and `:t (return 10 >>= \x -> fmap ($ x) f)` gives `(Num b, Functor m, Monad m) => m b`. Since it's generic in monad the `m` gets specialized to `IO` when you run it. A more common example of using the `(e ->)` monad is the `Reader` monad in `transformers` or `mtl`.

Answer (score 5):

This would be a lot easier to understand if Haskell allowed type operator
sections, IMO.  The type

```
a -> b
```

Is equivalent to

```
(->) a b
```

So that means that

```
(->) a
```

Is the same as

```
(a ->)
```

It's essentially saying that it's the function type parameterized over its
output type.  So this means that we should have

```
ret :: a -> (((->) r) a)
```

Or equivalently

```
ret :: a -> ((r ->) a)      -- Note that this is invalid Haskell, it's using our magical TypeOperatorSections extension
ret :: a -> (r -> a)
ret :: a -> r -> a
```

## WARNING: SPOILERS AHEAD!

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

Hmmm, this type looks very simple and familiar.  If we look it up on Hoogle, the
first result is

```
const :: a -> b -> a
```

And the rest of the results are about `seq`, `par`, and other more advanced
functions that we can be fairly certain aren't what we're looking for.  So
`const` it is:

```
instance MyMonad ((->) r) where
    return = const
```

For the implementation of `flatMap`, we can start by annotating our arguments
with their types:

```
flatMap (m :: r -> a) (f :: a -> (r -> b)) = _
```

So we have a function that when given `r` returns `a`, and a function which
given `a` and `r` returns `b`, and we want `flatMap m f :: r -> b`.  Since we
have no parameter with type `r`, let's introduce one:

```
flatMap m f = \r -> _
```

If you're using typed holes, GHC will now tell you that you need something of
type `b`.  The relevant bindings are

```
m :: r -> a
f :: a -> r -> b
r :: r
```

There's only one way to get `a`, and that's from `m`, so

```
flatMap m f = \r -> _ (m r)
```

Now we have GHC telling us we need something of type `a -> b`, with the relevant
bindings

```
f :: a -> r -> b
r :: r
```

This looks pretty straightforward to me:

```
flatMap m f = \r -> f (m r) r
```

And our code type checks!  Now time to test it out.  The desired behavior is
that we pass the same input argument to several functions in a do block (you
could use [`RebindableSyntax`](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-06-rebindable-syntax.html)
if you really wanted to use do notation), so something like

```
test :: Int -> Int
test =
    (*2) `flatMap` (\x1 ->
        (^3) `flatMap` (\x2 ->
            (7-) `flatMap` (\x3 ->
                return (x1 * x2 + x3)
            )
        )
    )
```

should be the same as

```
test' x = (2*x) * (x^3) + (7-x)
```

And for our implementation, it indeed works:

```
> test 5 == test' 5
True
> test 100 == test' 100
True
```

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth answer. How can I make an instance of `MyMonad`? I tried the following unsuccessfully: `ret (+ 10) :: MyMonad ((->) Int)` with the error: ` Expected a type, but `MyMonad ((->) Int)' has kind `Constraint'`

Comment: @KevinMeredith I'm not sure I follow you completely.  `MyMonad` is a typeclass, so if you want to make an instance of it you would use `instance MyMonad SomeType where ret = ...; flatMap = ...`.  Since `MyMonad` is a typeclass, you would use it as a constraint (the bit on the left side of a `=>`), like `MyMonad m => m ()`.  In this case I think you actually want `ret (+ 10) :: MyMonad m => m (Int -> Int)`.  The type `((->) Int)` needs another argument to indicate that it's actually a function.

Comment: @KevinMeredith If instead you're wanting to make `(->) Int` be your `m` in `MyMonad m => m something`, this doesn't really make sense in Haskell.  You wouldn't write `return () :: Monad IO => IO ()`, you'd just write `return () :: IO ()`.